# How do I suppress results from class function operations?

Tags: php

In this example code, I am running wild card searches in all the functions.
Chances are that function alkali() will give a right answer and the other function
a wrong answer and vice versa.

How do I suppress the fail part on one function once I get a right / correct answer
on another function?
I.e, I want to not show "metal is unknown" if I already show "this is an alkali metal".

```
<?php
class metals
{

    function alkali()
    {
        if (($rowC['description'] == " Alkali Metal")) {
            echo '';
        } else {
            echo 'metal is unknown';
        }

    }

    function alkaline_earth()
    {
        if (($rowC['description'] == " Alkali earth Metal")) {
            echo ' this is an alkali earth metal';
        } else {
            echo 'metal is unknown';
        }
    }
    //end of class    
}

// create an object for class name
$abc  = new metals();
$abcd = new metals();

// call the functions in the class
$abc->alkali();
$abcd->alkaline_earth();

?>
```

Comment: You would not have this problem if the functions had a single responsibility each (determine if an element is X) instead of two (determine and print the result). This way of doing things is just bad; refactor the code.

Comment: Make your functions `return` a result (probably just `true` or `false`), and then leave the logic of what to display when to a different part of the code, which can look at both results and decide what to do.

Comment: Also, the example code you give makes no sense, because `$rowC` isn't defined anywhere. I'm guessing you mean `$this->rowC` and intend it to be passed in when you create the object?

Comment: I just took a part of the whole code which works. This was part of two script files that i am putting together as a class. Only thing is i get a set of two answers all the time.One correct and the other is fail. I was looking for suggestions-- which i am getting now(So thanks). Also still new to classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter and more elegant way to achieve the wanted result is:

```
<?php

class metals {
    // Consider defining this as a static function if $rowC is not
    // intended to be a member of the class `metals`.
    function isMatch($search) {
        return $rowC['description'] == $search;
    }
}

$abc = new metals();
$searches = array('Alkali Metal', 'Alkali Earth Metal', 'Some Other Metal');

foreach ($searches as $search) {
    if ($abc->isMatch($search)) {
        echo 'Match found: ' . $search;
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

The loop will output the first match and then exit.

Comment: @edwinner: Make sure that `$rowC` is defined as a variable within the scope of the file where the code sample above would be located or within the global scope.

Comment: Great! i knew it had to do with a foreach loop.This will definitely work.